# Difference between symfony server and bin/console server?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I want to use the Symfony web server for local development, but I'm surprised that Symfony actually comes with **two** servers:

- the [Symfony local web server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html) - started with `symfony server:start`
- the [Web Server Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup/built_in_web_server.html) - started with `bin/console server:start`

I find it very confusing to have these 2 options, as the docs do not seem to give you any hint as to why you should use one over the other and under which circumstances.

As far as I can see, it looks like the Web Server Bundle (`bin/console server:start`):

- is just a wrapper around PHP's built-in web server
- is installed using Composer

while the Symfony local web server (`symfony server:start`):

- is a full-fledged web server
- must be [installed as standalone](https://symfony.com/download) (as part of the `symfony` command)

Still, I can hardly understand why they do release these 2 options. At first glance it looks like the Symfony local web server is more powerful; in this case why would they release the webserver bundle as well?

Comment: This is all in transition.  Docs need alot of work. The web server bundle was released several years ago and has been the default choice up until recently.  The symfony executable is a fairly recent development and it intended to replace the bundle.  The bundle itself will soon be removed from the default installation.  The symfony executable is almost identical except it makes it much easier to add security certificates.  Symfony wants you to use the executable as it also contains SymfonyCloud type commands.

Comment: Thank you, I'd accept this as an answer!

Comment: @Benjamin actually the `Web Server Bundle` docs that you've mentioned clearly say in a red bordered frame at the top of the page: "*This article explains how to use the web server based on the WebServerBundle. **This is no longer recommended in new Symfony applications. Instead, use the Symfony Local Web Server***"

Comment: That is all part of the "things are still in transition".  Should be cleared up in a few months when 4.4 is released.  I think I will pass on providing an actual answer.  Things are still changing too much.

Comment: @JakubMatczak Thanks, I don't know how I could overlook this message. I was focused on looking for the "deprecated" word I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Web Server Bundle docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup/built_in_web_server.html):

> Deprecated since version 4.4: This article explains how to use the WebServerBundle to run Symfony applications on your local computer. However, that bundle is deprecated since Symfony 4.4 and will be removed in Symfony 5.0.
>
> Instead of using WebServerBundle, the preferred way to run your Symfony applications locally is to use the Symfony Local Web Server.

So the recommended way is to use `symfony server:start` to serve an app in development.

Thanks to @Cerad and @Jakub Matczak for their comments.